# $ \mathcal O_K/(p) \cong \mathbb F_p[T]/(T^n)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a totally ramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ of degree $n$. Then $$
 \mathcal O_K/(p) \cong \mathbb F_p[T]/(T^n)
.$$ What is this isomorphism?

Comment: Let your uniformizer at $K$ be $\omega$, and $(p) = (\omega)^n$. Everything element in $\mathcal{O_K}$ is then a power series in $\omega$. The coefficients of the power series lie in $\mathcal{O_K}/(\omega)$. You then mod $\mathcal{O_K}$ by $(\omega^n)$ - does it ring a bell now?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understood last sentence at all. Can u explain it?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K/(\omega^n)$ should look like polynomials in $\omega$ wih degree less than $n$. Can you then write down an explicit isomorphism with $\mathbb{F}_p[T]/(T^n)$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's obvious indeed. I didn't realize that $1+(p-1)=\omega^n$ :)

Comment: not exactly - $p = w^n u$ for some unit $u$. I'm not sure why you need that though.